# Dynamically adding and removing CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a password strength bar which which uses `li` items which are styled with different colours to indicate to the user how strong their password is, like so:

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">

<ul id="passwordStrength">
    <li class="point-reg"></li>
    <li class="point-reg"></li>
    <li class="point-reg"></li>
    <li class="point-reg"></li>
</ul>
```

When a regEx criteria has been met through a set of `if` statements, the `counter` is incremented and a `switch` statement then adds the necessary CSS `background` property to each `li` item depending on the `counter` value.

```
var password_li = $('#passwordStrength').find('li');

var counter = 0;

if(pw.match(/[A-Z]/) && pw.match(/[a-z]/)) {
    counter++;
}

//further regex if statements

switch(counter) { //patrick
    case 0:
    break;
    case 1:
        $(password_li[0]).css('background', '#e30613'); //first li

    break;
    case 2:
        $(password_li[0]).css('background', '#e30613'); //first li
        $(password_li[1]).css('background', '#f9b233'); //second li         

    break;
    case 3:
        $(password_li[0]).css('background', '#e30613'); //first li
        $(password_li[1]).css('background', '#f9b233'); //second li                 
        $(password_li[2]).css('background', '#53ab58'); //third li                  

    break;
    case 4:
        $(password_li[0]).css('background', '#e30613'); //first li
        $(password_li[1]).css('background', '#f9b233'); //second li             
        $(password_li[2]).css('background', '#53ab58'); //third li                                  
        $(password_li[3]).css('background', '#418746'); //fourth li 
    break;
}
```

This doesn't seem the most efficient way of styling the `li` items. Also, if the user then deletes the value they have entered, the `li` items remain the colour they have been assigned, rather than reverting back to their default colour of grey, which makes sense as there isn't a function in place to remove the styling. I can add grey to the `li` items depending on what `case` has been met in the `switch` statement like so:

```
case 1:
    $(password_li[0]).css('background', '#e30613');
    $(password_li[1]).css('background', '#dcdcdc');                 
    $(password_li[2]).css('background', '#dcdcdc');                 
    $(password_li[3]).css('background', '#dcdcdc');                             
break;
```

But again, this does not seem the most efficient apporach.

***Question***

How do I approach this functionality so the styling for the `li` elements can be dynamically added and removed?

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vo4rpobb/)

Comment: can you provide a working snippet ? It is better to work with css classes than properties (add class, remove class)

Comment: I'll get onto making one

Comment: The ideal way to do this would be to push the values to a `data-` attribute and then read them in CSS via `attr()`, but unfortunately I don't think any browser currently supports that :(

Comment: Added fiddle guys

Comment: @delinear limited support or not support at all?

Comment: @PatrickMcDermott [no support at all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr#Browser_compatibility) right now (outside of using it with `content` in `::before` and `::after`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend adding/removing CSS classes rather than manipulating CSS rules.

You can persist which class to be add along with `<li>` element using custom `data-*` prefixed attribute.

Then you can target the elements on which classes needs to added using `.filter()` method and `:lt()` selector.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qprfzx0k/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var password_li = $('#passwordStrength').find('li');
  $('#password').bind('keyup', function() {
    var counter = 0;
    var pw = $(this).val();

    if (pw.length >= 8) {
      counter++;
    }
    if (pw.match(/\d/)) { //match digit
      counter++;
    }
    if (pw.match(/[A-Z]/) && pw.match(/[a-z]/)) { //match digit
      counter++;
    }
    if (pw.match(/[$@$!%*#?&]/)) { //match digit
      counter++;
    }
    //Get all classes to remove
    var clssesToRemove = password_li.map(function() {
      return $(this).data('matched-class');
    }).get().join(' ');

    //Remove all class
    password_li.removeClass(clssesToRemove);

    //Filter and add class
    password_li.filter(':lt(' + counter + ')').each(function() {
      $(this).addClass($(this).data('matched-class'));
    });

  })
})
```

```css
ul#strength {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: 2px;
}

.point-reg {
  background: #DDD;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  width: 30px;
}

.first {
  background-color: #e30613;
}

.second {
  background-color: #f9b233;
}

.third {
  background-color: #53ab58;
}

.fourth {
  background-color: #418746;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-8 offset-xl-2">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control pill-radius font-body" id="password" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <ul id="passwordStrength">
            <li class="point-reg" data-matched-class="first"></li>
            <li class="point-reg" data-matched-class="second"></li>
            <li class="point-reg" data-matched-class="third"></li>
            <li class="point-reg" data-matched-class="fourth"></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Satpal. Would of never though to ever take this apporach. Have never been one to utilize custom `data-` attributes.

Answer (score 2):

First, there's actually a method to remove the styling. Simply set it to nothing:

```
$(password_li[0]).css({
    background: ""
});
// I guess that can be done inline too
$(password_li[0]).css("background", "");
```

But if you prefer to do it with less iterations, you can do it with CSS classes. Just set your parent element a class and the class will have a `nth-child` selector that will set the color of each child, individually, depending on their position.

```
<style>
    .list1 > li:nth-child(1) {
        background: #e30613;
    }
    .list2 > li:nth-child(2) {
        background: #f9b233;
    }
    .list3 > li:nth-child(3) {
        background: #53ab58;
    }
    .list4 > li:nth-child(4) {
        background: #418746;
    }
    .list5 > li:nth-child(5) {
        background: red;
    }
    .list6 > li:nth-child(6) {
        background: blue;
    }
</style>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">

<ul id="passwordStrength">
    <li class="point-reg"></li>
    <li class="point-reg"></li>
    <li class="point-reg"></li>
    <li class="point-reg"></li>
</ul>
```

Then you can add the classes to the parent depending on the counter, like this

```
counter && $("#passwordStrength").addClass("list" + counter);
```

And remove them when not needed

```
while(counter) {
    $("#passwordStrength").removeClass("list" + counter--);
}
```

This way you can have the styles in other file, as recommended, instead of using inline styling, which is discouraged.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b6jfgyvy/

Comment: I am not sure this will work as expected. could you place the code in fiddle or here as a working snippet?

Comment: Are you saying place the `counter && $("#passwordStrength").addClass("list" + counter);` within the `switch` statement or remove the `switch` statement completely? I have tried your approach but no success I'm afraid

Comment: @PatrickMcDermott To remove the switch. Just add it after the counter is increased. Check the fiddle.

Comment: Thank @JorgeFuentesGonzález for your time and example. Didn't see the Fiddle

Comment: Nice Logic. +1 for your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this

```
colours = [
    '#e30613',
    '#f9b233',
    '#53ab58',
    '#53ab58'
];

for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    $("password_li[" + i + "]").css('background', colours[i]);
}
```

You can reset all colours by:

```
$("password_li").css('background', '#dcdcdc');
```